# Importing Unicode XML code SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sqlxml

I am trying to import XML data from the following webpage: http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml. This is a continuously updating webpage and I want my SQL code to obtain the latest values.

If I manually download the xml file to my computer and run my SQL code, it works without any issues:

```
DECLARE @xmlFile XML
SET @xmlFile = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\sqlfreaq\Desktop\today.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS xmldata)

SELECT @xmlFile.value('(Tarih_Date/Currency/ForexSelling)[1]', 'decimal(18,5)') AS DatabaseID
```

However, when I try to use OLE stored procedures to import data, some of the Unicode characters change and as a result, the XML cannot be parsed. My code is as follows:

```
DECLARE    @url VARCHAR(300),
    @win INT,
    @hr INT,
    @xml xml



SET    @url = 'http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml'

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @win OUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win


Create table #tmp(dt nvarchar(max))
insert into #tmp exec @hr =sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText'

Select 
CAST(CAST([dt] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML) TT
from #tmp -- single column/single row.
Drop Table #tmp -- clean up

EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @win 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win
```

However, if I use this code to get data from a NON-UNICODE xml file (just change the website in the code from http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml to http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml, it works. How, can I modify my code or method, so that I can use the online XML file.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just another option

**Example**

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml" -OutFile "c:\working\today.xml"',no_output

Declare @XML xml; 
Select @XML = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\working\today.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x; 

Select [CrossOrder]      = lvl1.n.value('@CrossOrder'       ,'int')
      ,[Kod]             = lvl1.n.value('@Kod'              ,'nvarchar(50)')  -- Set desired data tyoe
      ,[CurrencyCode]    = lvl1.n.value('@CurrencyCode'     ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[Unit]            = lvl1.n.value('Unit[1]'           ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[Isim]            = lvl1.n.value('Isim[1]'           ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[CurrencyName]    = lvl1.n.value('CurrencyName[1]'   ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[ForexBuying]     = lvl1.n.value('ForexBuying[1]'    ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[ForexSelling]    = lvl1.n.value('ForexSelling[1]'   ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[BanknoteBuying]  = lvl1.n.value('BanknoteBuying[1]' ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[BanknoteSelling] = lvl1.n.value('BanknoteSelling[1]','nvarchar(50)')
      ,[CrossRateUSD]    = lvl1.n.value('CrossRateUSD[1]'   ,'nvarchar(50)')
      ,[CrossRateOther]  = lvl1.n.value('CrossRateOther[1]' ,'nvarchar(50)')
 From  @XML.nodes('Tarih_Date/Currency') lvl1(n)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Great solution, but it's worth to mention, that `BULK` can deal with `UTF-8` not before [v2014 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780)

Comment: @Shnugo Hey there you are!   Good to know.  I only encountered something like this years ago when I was with the bank.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution, just an explanation where the code fails:

The problem is here and is two-folded:

```
Select 
CAST(CAST([dt] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML) TT
```

The conversion to `VARCHAR`, instead of `NVARCHAR` will destroy characters which are not covered by your `VARCHAR's` collation.

The second problem is, that your XML starts with a directive, stating the encoding to be `UTF-8`. But the actual data is `UTF-16` (actually it is `UCS-2`).

Change it to this and it will work

```
Select 
CAST(REPLACE(CAST([dt] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'UTF-8','UTF-16') AS XML) TT
```

The problem is, that not all characters will be displayed correctly...

**some more background**

The last parameter, which you set to 'false', is not meant to state the encoding (as suggested elsewhere), but a [`sync/async` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383989(v=vs.85).aspx), this won't help...

You might import this to a `VARBINARY(MAX)` variable, but SQL-Server will not be able to deal with the `utf-8` encoded string natively.

John's solution is great, but I think, it will need [at least *v2014 SP2*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the last parameter to `True`, in `sp_OAMethod` call. Something like as shown below.

```
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, True
```

False - is for ANSI

True - is for UNICODE

Look into below link and search for Unicode.

http://notes.szemtsov.com/?p=73&print=print

Comment: I made that change, but now I get a NULL value as an output of my SELECT statement